# Importer mapping issue with Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, import, controller

I'm hoping someone might be able to look over my code.

I'm trying to import records using Maat Excel, but it seems to not want to pull a few columns when I try to import.

At the moment, here is my one row test to explain my problem.

```
bill_to,date,pro_number,sent_on,due_date,shipment_billing_status,ship_to,tractor_id,driver_id,trailer_id,miles,loadDiscountDesc,loadDiscountAmt,fuelChargeDesc,fuelChargeAmt,fuelChargeTotal,permitChargeDesc,permitChargeAmt,permitChargeTotal,otherChargeDesc,otherChargeAmt,otherChargeTotal,Total,balance,shipper_no,load_date,cn_shiptoName,cn_shiptoAddress1,ship_from,created_at,cn_shiptoAddress2,cn_shiptoCity,cn_shiptoState,cn_shiptoZip,cn_shipfromName,cn_shipfromAddress1,cn_shipfromAddress2,cn_shipfromCity,cn_shipfromState,cn_shipfromZip,cn_billtoName,cn_billtoAddress1,cn_billtoAddress2,cn_billtoCity,cn_billtoState,cn_billtoZip,bill_type,print_date,shipment_origin,void,import_balance,import_payments,freightBillSubtotal
157,2017-06-13,213782,,2017-07-13,5,302,,,,,,0,,,,,0,0,,0,,0,0,54451935,2017-06-13,,,,2017-06-13 00:00:00,,,,,fISHER PRICE,501 MEACHAM BLVD,,FORT WORTH,TX,76106,,,,,,,4,,1,,0,0,0
```

As you can see, one field in particular "cn_shipfromName" is filled with: fISHER PRICE.

But if you see this error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'cn_shipfromName' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `shipments` (`bill_to`, `date`, `pro_number`, `sent_on`, `due_date`, `shipment_billing_status`, `ship_to`, `tractor_id`, `driver_id`, `trailer_id`, `miles`, `fuelChargeDesc`, `fuelChargeAmt`, `fuelChargeTotal`, `permitChargeDesc`, `permitChargeAmt`, `permitChargeTotal`, `otherChargeDesc`, `otherChargeAmt`, `otherChargeTotal`, `Total`, `shipper_no`, `load_date`, `cn_shiptoName`, `cn_shiptoAddress1`, `cn_shiptoAddress2`, `cn_shiptoCity`, `ship_from`, `created_at`, `cn_shiptoState`, `cn_shiptoZip`, `cn_shipfromName`, `cn_shipfromAddress1`, `cn_shipfromAddress2`, `cn_shipfromCity`, `cn_shipfromState`, `cn_shipfromZip`, `cn_billtoName`, `cn_billtoAddress1`, `cn_billtoAddress2`, `cn_billtoCity`, `cn_billtoState`, `cn_billtoZip`, `bill_type`, `print_date`, `shipment_origin`, `void`, `import_balance`, `import_payments`, `freightBillSubtotal`, `created_by`, `updated_at`) values (157, 2017-06-13, 213782, , 2017-07-13, 5, 302, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , 54451935, 2017-06-13, , , , , , 2017-06-13 00:00:00, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , 4, , 1, , 0, 0, , 1, 2017-12-22 06:22:26))
```

You see fISHER PRICE is left off, as are a few other values.

Right now, this is my controller:

```
public function importShipments (Request $request)
{
    if($request->file('imported-file'))
  {
            $path = $request->file('imported-file')->getRealPath();
            $data = Excel::load($path, function($reader) {
                })->get();
                if(!empty($data) && $data->count()){
                    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                        $user = Auth::user()->id;
                        Shipment::create([
                          'bill_to' => $value->bill_to,
                          'date' => $value->date,
                          'pro_number' => $value->pro_number,
                          'sent_on' => $value->sent_on,
                          'due_date' => $value->due_date,
                          'shipment_billing_status' => $value->shipment_billing_status,
                          'ship_to' => $value->ship_to,
                          'tractor_id' => $value->tractor_id,
                          'driver_id' => $value->driver_id,
                          'trailer_id' => $value->trailer_id,
                          'miles' => $value->miles,
                          'loadDiscountDesc' => $value->loadDiscountDesc,
                          'loadDiscountAmt' => $value->loadDiscountAmt,
                          'fuelChargeDesc' => $value->fuelChargeDesc,
                          'fuelChargeAmt' => $value->fuelChargeAmt,
                          'fuelChargeTotal' =>$value->fuelChargeTotal,
                          'permitChargeDesc' => $value->permitChargeDesc,
                          'permitChargeAmt' => $value->permitChargeAmt,
                          'permitChargeTotal' => $value->permitChargeTotal,
                          'otherChargeDesc' => $value->otherChargeDesc,
                          'otherChargeAmt' => $value->otherChargeAmt,
                          'otherChargeTotal' => $value->otherChargeTotal,
                          'Total' => $value->Total,
                          'balance' =>$value->balance,
                          'shipper_no' => $value->shipper_no,
                          'load_date' => $value->load_date,
                          'cn_shiptoName' => $value->cn_shiptoName,
                          'cn_shiptoAddress1' => $value->cn_shiptoAddress1,
                          'cn_shiptoAddress2' => $value->cn_shiptoAddress2,
                          'cn_shiptoCity' => $value->cn_shiptoCity,
                          'ship_from' => $value->ship_from,
                          'created_at' =>$value->created_at,
                          'cn_shiptoState' => $value->cn_shiptoState,
                          'cn_shiptoZip' => $value->cn_shiptoZip,
                          'cn_shipfromName' => $value->cn_shipfromName,
                          'cn_shipfromAddress1' => $value->cn_shipfromAddress1,
                          'cn_shipfromAddress2' => $value->cn_shipfromAddress2,
                          'cn_shipfromCity' =>$value->cn_shipfromCity,
                          'cn_shipfromState' =>$value->cn_shipfromState,
                          'cn_shipfromZip' => $value->cn_shipfromZip,
                          'cn_billtoName' => $value->cn_billtoName,
                          'cn_billtoAddress1' => $value->cn_billtoAddress1,
                          'cn_billtoAddress2' => $value->cn_billtoAddress2,
                          'cn_billtoCity' => $value->cn_billtoCity,
                          'cn_billtoState' => $value->cn_billtoState,
                          'cn_billtoZip' => $value->cn_billtoZip,
                          'bill_type' =>$value->bill_type,
                          'print_date' => $value->print_date,
                          'shipment_origin' => $value->shipment_origin,
                          'void' => $value->void,
                          'import_balance' => $value->import_balance,
                          'import_payments' => $value->import_payments,
                          'freightBillSubtotal' => $value->freightBillSubtotal,
                          'created_at' => $value->created_at,
                            'created_by' => $user,
                        ]);
                    }
                }
            }
    Session::flash('flash_message','Database successfully imported!');
    return back();
}
```

and this is my SHIPMENT model with the parts specific to this issue:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Shipment_Status;
use App\Shipment_Billing_Status;
use App\Shipment_Type;
use OwenIt\Auditing\Contracts\Auditable;

class Shipment extends Model implements Auditable
{
    use \OwenIt\Auditing\Auditable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'pro_number', 
        'shipment_origin',
        'notes',
        'shipment_status',
        'shipment_billing_status',
        'due_date',
        'date',
        'description',
        'driver_id',
        'tractor_id',
        'trailer_id',
        'shipper_no',
        'ship_to',
        'ship_from',
        'bill_to',
        'bill_type',
        'load_date',
        'cn_billtoName',
        'cn_billtoAddress1',
        'cn_billtoAddress2',
        'cn_billtoCity',
        'cn_billtoState',
        'cn_billtoZip',
        'cn_billtoPhone',
        'cn_billtoEmail',
        'cn_shiptoName',
        'cn_shiptoAddress1',
        'cn_shiptoAddress2',
        'cn_shiptoCity',
        'cn_shiptoState',
        'cn_shiptoZip',
        'cn_shiptoPhone',
        'cn_shiptoEmail',
        'cn_shipfromName',
        'cn_shipfromAddress1',
        'cn_shipfromAddress2',
        'cn_shipfromCity',
        'cn_shipfromState',
        'cn_shipfromZip',
        'cn_shipfromPhone',
        'cn_shipfromEmail',
        'fuelChargeDesc',
        'fuelChargeAmt',
        'fuelChargeTotal',
        'permitChargeDesc',
        'permitChargeAmt',
        'permitChargeTotal',
        'otherChargeDesc',
        'otherChargeAmt',
        'otherChargeTotal',
        'noCharge',
        'noSettle',
        'Total',
        'freightBillSubtotal',
        'sent_on',
        'created_at',
        'print_date',
        'void',
        'import_payments',
        'import_balance',
        'miles',
        'sent_on',
        'created_by'
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

If some columns like `cn_shipfromName` are allowed to be empty you have to add `->nullable()` to your migrations

```
$table->string('cn_shipfromName')->nullable();
```

and rerun the very migration:

```
php artisan migrate:refresh --path=/path/to/the/migrationfile
```

If empty values are not allowed your validation should mark them als invalid and exclude it from the import.

Comment: Well they are allowed to be nullable. But what I am saying is the values from the csv file aren't being pulled, like I said above, while you can see the value in the csv file row, you cannot see them in the sql error.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your `$value` to array then fill your model with it.

```php
$input = $value->toArray();
$shipment = new Shipment;
$shipment->fill($value);
$shipment->save();
```

Then to investigate what is causing the issue, you can dump your shipment object then check what values are assigned in it before saving :

```php
$shipment->fill($value);
dd($shipment);
$shipment->save();
```